# Retrieving file path with escape character from database in dataGridView DataRow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am storing various data in a MS Access database file and filling it into a dataGridView. One of the columns is a field that stores a file location. If I load up the databse file I can see it is stored as

```
D:\test\1.txt
```

Now I try to retrieve it using the following

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
     string Location = row["file_location"].ToString();
}
```

When I examine the debug watch window I can see that `string Location` is actually `D:\\test\\1.txt` now I understand it is adding a `\` as an escape character but I am unsure how to get my `string Location` to actually hold the correct path rather than the escaped path.

I tried adding a verbatim string literal in a couple of ways but I was not sure it was going to effect it in the way I had read about especially if it was already pulled from the database file or even if I was putting it in the correct place.

I tried the two options below but I was not confident either was going to work, And they did not in the end.

```
string Location = @"";
Location = row["file_location"].ToString();
```

And

```
string Location = @row["file_location"].ToString();
```

hoping someone could help me out with this. I have read so many StackOverflow articles and i cant seem to find something that speaks to my specific issue in a way I could understand

Answer (score 1):

The verbatim string ([discussed in this stackoverflow question](http://goo.gl/EgTszM)) is really for a compile time literal and not at all useful for a value assigned at runtime.

It looks like the only escape character you're worried about is the backslash so a very quick fix for your troubles would be this:

```
string Location = row["file_location"].ToString().Replace("\\","\");
```

There may be more elegant ways of course.

*Update:*

As discussed, you are maybe not understanding the watch window.  Those strings are escaped regardless of actual value.  consider:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        watchisescaping();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void watchisescaping()
    {
        string location = @"c:\dim\bulbs";
        Console.WriteLine(location);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The watch window shows location as `c:\\dim\\bulbs` but the console output is `c:\dim\bulbs` as it should be.  Are you certain that the string is really still escaped when you view it in the datagrid?

Comment: I got an error about a newline in a constant so i changed it to

string replaceWith = @"\";
string Location = row["file_location"].ToString().Replace("\\", replaceWith);

However the debug watch still shows it with double backslahes it doesnt seem to be replacing it

Comment: I think your debug watch may be re-escaping it for you.  Let me replicate that in my project.

Comment: Thats a bit frustrating, I rely on the watch for checking alot of variables guess I will have to re-evaluate what I am looking at. But I had assumed that was the reason my code was not working correctly as it was never finding the correct file location. Guess I have more work to do

Comment: Check out the text visualizer that the watch window (and locals, and autos) will provide for text values.  It's a little magnifying glass icon.

Comment: Was not aware of the text visualizer but it seems very useful. Thanks for the heads up!